# Calculating mean value for all pixels within given distance for all pixels in study area using raster analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, distance, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics

I am working in QGIS

I have a raster layer depicting the population density for a country. A portion of this raster layer is used as a study area.

I want to know for each pixel in that study area what's the mean population density value for all points within say, 15 km of that pixel.

Where do I start?

Comment: So you have two rasters, one with locations and one with populations? Or one raster of locations and one vector feature class with population?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. We are not a tutorial site, but a problem-solving one. Unfortunately, "Where do I start?" questions are off-topic here. Questions in GIS SE should state what GIS software is in use, what has been attempted, and what error/problem has been encountered.

Comment: I'm using QGIS; using one raster (or at least, the output raster needs to have the same resolution as the density raster).

Comment: What you would need is a focal statistics tool  which is currently not implemented in QGIS. You can try to use the GRASS GIS tool r.neighbours for that. https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.neighbors.html

Comment: This worked, thanks. The only problem was that this couldn't handle large data volumes, so I had to warp to a lower resolution, and limit the radius. Otherwise, it was fine.